# How to convert Java EE struts2 regular project into maven support project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, servlets, netbeans, struts2

I am trying to add maven support for my existing project.I couldn't found any complete guide for this. I just converted it by creating a new maven based project and pasting the source files inside the source packages. I set the pom xml too.Project was built successfully. And run without a problem.

But the problem is, I want to connect this project's action class method form another regular project's servlet. Previous project(not the maven project) connected successfully, but the created maven project is not connected.

**HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL**

This error is returned.I think there may be a mistake in maven project creation. Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

here is my servlet code that I used to connect maven project action class

```
 private String getUrlOfReportModule() throws Exception {
    String reportUrl = null;
    try {
        commonParamManager = new CommonParamManager();
        //reportUrl = commonParamManager.getUrlOfReportModule();
        reportUrl = "http://localhost:8090/DF_MY_REPORT/";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return reportUrl + "checkLoginActionMgt.htm";
}
```

here is my jsp code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        document.userDetails.action = "${redirectUrl}";
        document.userDetails.submit();
});

    <form  style="display: none" method="POST" name="userDetails" id="userDeatils">

</form>
```

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided. Sounds like the endpoint you're hitting isn't a POST endpoint.

Comment: can you please more details about the issue. And also please let me to know what type of details you want form my side to get a better understanding on the issue.